# Phonegap/Cordova - Where is cdvfile://localhost in terms of the app root?

Tags: javascript, cordova, filesystems, phonegap-build

I am currently exploring different options for storing files on my app I am building, however I have noticed different file structures present in phone gap and don't know which is the most up to date.

Using: `alert(JSON.stringify(fileSystem.root));` I can see that `fileSystem.root.nativeURL` is file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/APPID/Documents, but cannot find where cdvfile://localhost is located.

Is this the root of the app and also is fileSystem.root.nativeURL still used to add files to the apps Documents folder?

Thanks

-- Current Code --

```
function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
        }

        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(fileSystem.root));
            return;
            fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android phone then if you will define the storage location type like internal or external

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

then it will save the file to the root of internal or external storage.

if you are working with ios then you have to install [itunesfilesharing](https://github.com/christianjunk/cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing) plugin that will share the file in app documents folder.here the config.xml

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Documents" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Ali, once done would I call cdvfile://localhost, or the fileSystem.root.nativeURL to get to the iOS documents folder?

Comment: I had simply passed file Entry object to Read File function for that.

Comment: fileSystem.root.nativeURL you will use this one. I got it sorry . I was confused about it

Comment: Thanks Hassan, what does cdvfile://localhost specify then? If I was to save a file to cdvfile://localhost/data where about would the data directory be in regards to the www root directory?

Comment: Sorry i don't know what cdvfile://localhost  specify .But as per my understanding you will not able find your data directory in www root directory . you will get this information in the plugin native files.

Comment: Hmm its just I've read in the latest version when you require saving to persist, you must specify cdvfile://localhost/persistent as the other method has been depreciated. Does that help with any insight into what it might be?

Comment: May be it will . Can you share link . So i also can read now.

Comment: Theres a few places, however here is someone discussing what it does: http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/the-right-location-for-your-cordova-app-files